# Using xscan for books

Tags: scanner

I want to use **xscan** to scan pages from a book, so I can't use the automatic feed. I'm running ubuntu 18,04 with a dcp7065 printer/scanner. When I bring up **xscan**, it selects ajtomatic  feed with no alternatives.  I need to run it in the manual scan, multiple page mode to scan the book.  How can I achieve that?

The procedure must activate the Scan button. Once it has been activated, I can then proceed by pressing the Scan button, which will cause the page to be scanned. I then load the second page and press the button again. My problem is getting the Scan button to respond the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You may be in luck with your Brother printer/scanner because the company is great with their Linux support.

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7065dn_all

Sorry I posted an invalid URL on my last post.  Please try this one.

I recommend downloading the deb package for their scanners.
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7065dn_all&os=128

Comment: The second URL produces an unexplained error.